# How do I preserve internally-created trailing zeros when exporting a CSV from R?

Tags: r, csv

First, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60495444/exporting-csv-in-r-with-trailing-zeros) question is very close, but not quite what I need. Allow me to explain:

I am working with a series of data which requires me to tag according to an internal standard in which decimal places are used as separators. A generic example is below:

```
ItemA  1.6            
ItemB  1.7             
ItemB  1.8
ItemB  1.9
ItemB  1.10
```

Now, when this data gets exported as a csv file, the `1.10` gets changed to `1.1`. We already use `1.1` for something else, and unlike the linked question above, this tagging is done *in the program*. The data that is read in for processing does not contain the numbers. For reasons that are irritating, the output must be a csv, and I cannot change how the tagging is done. The output csv file goes elsewhere for further processing by someone else. Changing the class of the value does not have any effect, it seems.

Added in from my comment to the first answer, for clarification: I try to tag as 1.10 in R, and it becomes 1.1 instead, mixing with my other 1.1. To avoid this, I have made them as.character('1.10') but that still doesn't help with the exported csv file. At no point is a csv containing '1.10' being read in.

Is there any way to get r to write the `1.10` into the csv? I don't care how involved or "janky" it is.

Comment: You'll need to convert those numeric values to character values if you want to control for zeros at the end of the string. Once the value is numeric, R can no longer track leading/trailing zeros. I'm not sure where the values are coming from but if you are importing them then make sure to import them as character values from the start.

Comment: @MrFlick they are not being imported, and I am creating them as characters right from their first appearance in an effort to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Going on a different tangent -- another approach is to separate the components of each `xxx.yyy` and store them as two integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `colClasses` in `read.csv`.

Let's make a reproducible example:

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemB", "ItemB", "ItemB"), 
                 col2 = c("1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9", "1.10"))

write.csv(df, file = "my.csv", quote = FALSE)
```

So now my.csv looks like this:

```
,col1,col2
1,ItemA,1.6
2,ItemB,1.7
3,ItemB,1.8
4,ItemB,1.9
5,ItemB,1.10
```

And we can reproduce your problem by doing:

```r
read.csv("my.csv", row.names = 1)
#>    col1 col2
#> 1 ItemA  1.6
#> 2 ItemB  1.7
#> 3 ItemB  1.8
#> 4 ItemB  1.9
#> 5 ItemB  1.1
```

But if we specify `colClasses`, the problem is resolved:

```r
read.csv("my.csv", row.names = 1, colClasses = c("character", "character"))
#>    col1 col2
#> 1 ItemA  1.6
#> 2 ItemB  1.7
#> 3 ItemB  1.8
#> 4 ItemB  1.9
#> 5 ItemB 1.10
```

Comment: Nice. You could have used `row.names=F` in `write.csv()` to get rid of row names while saving objects in csv

Comment: Probably confused abit: Isnt the problem OP has is to write to the csv file and not to read from the csv file? Seems OP is trying to export from R and not import to R. Or Am I reading it incorrectly?

Comment: @Onyambu maybe I'm confused too. The OP says the data appears as 1.10 in R. Presumably if it was numeric, it would be 1.1 in R? In any case if it is already 1.1 in R then the information is already lost.

Comment: Yes, I try to tag as 1.10 in R, and it becomes 1.1 instead, mixing with my other 1.1. To avoid this, I have made them ```as.character('1.10')``` but that still doesn't help with the exported csv file. At no point is a csv containing '1.10' being read in.

Comment: If the column is a character column, it will write as a character column in the csv, as I show above. Could you give an example of your actual data using `dput`?

Comment: But I am trying to write a csv. Not read one. And my actual data in this case is literally just 1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.10.

Comment: I know, but there are several ways to have that data in R. If you use dput to show us the actual structure of the data, I'm sure we can get this working. You can see from my example above that the csv file has 1.10 in it, not 1.1, so there's something that's not right with either your code or your data that isn't apparent in the question or comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share any data directly. I am not familiar with dput, but it seems using it would require me to show some actual data. Having said that, though, your very first part above, where you create csv, should indeed be something I can do. I will play with that.

Comment: An example with made up data that replicates the problem would be fine.

Comment: Ok, one moment. Apologies. This is one of like 80 things I'm doing work-wise at the moment. I will update today.